# click twice on button process the ngIf statement in other component

Tags: javascript, angular, variables, angular-ng-if

I've added breadcrumb in my site such that when clicks on it, it makes that specific variable undefined(which session stored value and can retrieved easily in other component) and based on that, in other component I've ngIf for that variable such that if that variable is undefined then that specific div should not be shown and other div should be shown. You can get more idea by looking into following gifs.

Problem I'm facing is on first click it don't go back to that other div which it does on second click.

[image]
Clicking twice on breadcrumb for Model(or its value) do the trick but i want to do this happens on first click.

Breadcrumb component TS file:

```
@SessionStorage() model: any;
onClickModel(m){
    this.model = m.value; // gets the value from button and set as model value
  }
```

other component HTML file:

```
<div class="model" *ngIf="model && !provider">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center pb-20">
        <h2>Choose your Carrier</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <!-- That next component buttons for providers -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: let me add code, i thought it might be clear from scenario and as there is no such errors in code.

Comment: @BirjuShah code added, kindly have a look

Comment: It is difficult to say from your description, that what exactly are you trying to achieve. May be you can add a plunkr

Comment: Thanks, i solved this problem and I will add solution asap